# SCSS: :nth-of-type() on specific class

Tags: html, css, sass

So I've never run into this problem before, that's why I might be so confused. Consider the following:

```css
.container .box {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

conatainer .box.fancy:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box fancy"></span>
  <span class="box fancy"></span>
  <span class="box fancy"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
</div>
```

I want to select the second element with the class `.fancy`. I've tried it with `:nth-child()` as well. Is it even possible using only CSS?

Comment: its already working, what do you want ?

Comment: no it's not, it is in fact selecting the second `.first` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kinda can, but need some workaround:

```css
.container {
  counter-reset: boxes;
}

.box {
  counter-increment: boxes;
}

.box::before {
  content: 'Box ' counter(boxes);
}

/* set color for all .box starting from the second .fancy class */
.box.fancy ~ .box.fancy {
  color: red;
}


/* reset the color for all .box starting from the third .fancy class */
.box.fancy ~ .box.fancy ~ .box.fancy {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box fancy"></span>
  <span class="box fancy"></span><!-- selected -->
  <span class="box fancy"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="box fancy"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box fancy"></span><!-- selected -->
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="box fancy"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box fancy"></span><!-- selected -->
  <span class="box fancy"></span>
  <span class="box fancy"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working, but unfortunately my HTML is generated by javascript. I was hoping for an easier solution. Still gave you an upvote.

Comment: @Dop4miN I don't know this solution has anything to do with the html code. The html code I'm showing you just a demonstration that which element will be effected. The solution is the css, only.